# What Would Happen If Lightning Struck A Whirlpool/Maelstrom?

Tags: lightning

Theoretically, if lightning were to strike a whirlpool or maelstrom, what would happen to the lightning? This may seem like a silly question, but I really have no clue. Would the centrifugal force of the whirlpool do anything to the direction the  lightning spreads out in? Would it be pulled down to the center of the whirlpool? I have no clue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see - not really.

Here's the thing: lightning is just a discharge from the sky - or clouds - to the ground (or in this case, water.) The discharge is very, very quick, which is why some people have survived being hit by it due to how short the exposure was to that high a voltage. So, if lightning hit a whirlpool or for that matter any moving target, the discharge would just "zap" to the target, and when the discharge is over, well, the lightning is gone. I guess you could technically say that the lightning is "moving" because the place where it's discharging to is also moving, but the effect would hardly be noticeable.